# Why the same statement doesn't work for Class member in C++?

Tags: c++, class, vector, nested, initialization

I'm very new to C++ and below is my program. It defines a nested vector.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<vector<int>> grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000));
    return 0;
}
```

When I define the same vector as a class member, it reports syntax error:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000));
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<vector<int>> grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I define a class member of type `vector<vector<int>>` and initialize it with 10 `vector<int>(10, 10000)`? I tried to declare the variable and initialize it in the constructor, but the compiler reports `C:\my_projects\cpp1\main.cpp(8): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments`.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000));
    }

public:
    vector<vector<int>> grid;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<vector<int>> grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I'm very new to C++` This is why you should be using a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). C++ is complex, trying to learn it from miscellaneous internet sources and intuition is not going to get you very far, very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use braced initializer or equal-sign initializer for [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11), which doesn't support parentheses initializer; as the error message said, it attempts to be interpreted as function.

E.g.

```
class Test {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> grid{10, vector<int>(10, 10000)};
};
```

or

```
class Test {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> grid = vector<vector<int>>(10, vector<int>(10, 10000));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I have one more question. Why `vector<long> numbers{20, 99L};` means initialize a vector with two initial values, but `vector<vector<int>> grid{10, vector<int>(10, 10000)};` means 10 `vector<int>(10, 10000)`?

Comment: @Justalearner Because `std::vector` has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking `std::initializer_list` (#10 in the linked page), which is preferred when initialized with braced-initializer. `{10, vector<int>(10, 10000)}` can't construct a valid `std::initializer_list`, then `vector<vector<int>> grid{10, vector<int>(10, 10000)};` will use the #3 constructor.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor initializer is wrong. It should be (initializer(s) after ':').
Example ([Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/004001089d48e030)):

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() : grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000))
    {
         // grid(10, vector<int>(10, 10000)); error: this is not initializer
         // grid = vector<vector<int>>(10, vector<int>(10, 10000)) - this is ok
    }

public:
    vector<vector<int>> grid;
};
```

and for in-class member initialization you can use curly braces '{' or '=' to avoid most [vexing parse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) ([Live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5074e1b8f5df79)):

```
class Test {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> grid{10, vector<int>(10, 10000)};
};
```